# Unable to reformat partition booted from Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

On Ubuntu 16, after attempting to resize a partition I rebooted and received this error on boot:

```
error: failure writing sector 0xf579808 to 'hd0'
```

So I booted Ubuntu 20 Live from a USB. Here is what I've attempted:

1. In Disks, verified that /dev/sdb5 is the main linux file system and ran a check on that partition. Returned "Filesystem needs repairing" message.
2. Using GParted, attempted a repair on that partition which returned this:

```
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/sdb5'  00:00:11    ( ERROR )
        
/dev/sdb5: recovering journal

/dev/sdb5: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/sdb5
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdb5
```

3. Using GParted, attempted to reformat the partition (I don't care about preserving data). Returned this

```
Device: /dev/sdb
Model:  ATA INTEL SSDSCKKF18
Serial: CVLY737502M9180C
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  351651888
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  689513
 
Partition table:    gpt
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sdb1   Primary 2048    534527  boot, hidden, esp   EFI system partition    fat32   SYSTEM  
/dev/sdb2   Primary 534528  567295  msftres Microsoft reserved partition    unknown 

/dev/sdb3   Primary 567296  67035823    msftdata    Basic data partition    ntfs    Windows 
/dev/sdb5   Primary 67037184    333023231   

ext4    

/dev/sdb6   Primary 333023232   349603839   swap    
linux-swap  

/dev/sdb4   Primary 349603840   351651839   hidden, diag    
ntfs    WinRE_DRV   
========================================

Format /dev/sdb5 as cleared  00:00:04    ( ERROR )
        
calibrate /dev/sdb5  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sdb5 (partition)
start: 67037184
end: 333023231
size: 265986048 (126.83 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdb5  00:00:03    ( ERROR )
        
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 136184332288  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 136184791040  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 136184848384  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sdb  00:00:03    ( ERROR )
        
libparted messages    ( ERROR )
        
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
```

4. Used smartctl to check hard drive health

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2796         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2793         -
```

Also ran a long test and results showed no errors.

I care nothing about saving data on this hard drive, just trying to get the machine to boot up.

Comment: if libparted can't write to sdb5 some hardware must be broken. I wouldn't trust that disk anymore. Can windows format it?

Comment: Not sure about Windows, haven't tried it.